# How to get name of type contained within missing assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have loaded assembly `A` in `ReflectionOnly` context in order to get information on types and their methods. At least one of methods has return type that is part of dependency assembly `B`.

The problem is that assembly `B` is not available and cannot be resolved so following `FileNotFoundException` is thrown:

> Could not load file or assembly 'B' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

That exception is kind of expected. However, I have seen that `Reflector` CAN load type name (which is what I need) even when it cannot resolve dependency assembly.

Does someone know how to get name of type contained within missing assembly without getting `FileNotFoundException`?

**EDIT:**

Exception is thrown when trying to access `ReturnType` property:

```
Type returnType = methodInfo.ReturnType;
```

Comment: Can you post a code sample and tell us which line exactly throws the exception?

Comment: I don't believe reflector uses the reflection APIs ... it builds its own code dom by inspecting the IL directly

Comment: You are finding out that Lutz Roeder is a pretty cool programmer.  He didn't use Type, he parses the assembly metadata directly.  Chuck Norris uses IMetaDataAssemblyImport too.

Comment: @Hans: I am not sure whether Lutz Roeder really did it. For some reason I think he used `Mono.Cecil` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a different library to load this assembly, like [`Mono.Cecil`](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).

Answer (score 0):

Ok... there is a "weird" possible solution, I say, it's "weird".

Each time you try to load a class that cannot be found in an AppDomain, AppDomain.TypeResolve event is raised.

[See the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.typeresolve%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Now... we leave multithreading and multiple app domain issues apart for now, for the sake of keeping things simple, but if you add an handler to AppDomain.Current.TypeResolve you can find the name of the missing class.

Comment: ``TypeResolve`` event is not fired. According to MSDN, "... this event does not occur if the type is not found in a static assembly because the runtime knows types cannot be added dynamically to static assemblies.". It seems the reflected assembly is a static one. Anyway, thanks.